# exception on buttonclick using dictionary

Tags: c#, user-interface

i am trying to use a function on button click but every time it throws an exception

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at gui.Form9.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

even though it is included in the dictionary which is read from a text file.

here's my code for the button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Program.AllCourses.ContainsKey(courseid))
            {
                if (Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student.id].coursesIP.Contains(courseid))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have already registered for this course !", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else if (Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student.id].coursesF.Contains(courseid))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have already finished this course !", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else if (Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student.id].coursesF.Contains(Program.AllCourses[courseid].prerequired_courses))
                {

                        if (Program.AllCourses[courseid].number_current_students < Program.AllCourses[courseid].number_max_students)
                        {
                        Program.AllStudents[Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student.id].id].coursesIP.Add(courseid);
                        Program.AllStudents[Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student.id].id].noCoursesIP++;

                            Program.AllCourses[courseid].number_current_students++;
                            Program.AllCourses[courseid].enrolled_students.Add(Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student.id].name);
                        Program.SaveSerial();
                        Program.SaveCourses();
                        MessageBox.Show("You Have Succesfully Registered to the course.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    }
                    else
                        {
                        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, This course had reached its maximum number of students.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


                    }



                }
                else if (Program.AllCourses[courseid].prerequired_courses == "None")
                {


                        if (Program.AllCourses[courseid].number_current_students < Program.AllCourses[courseid].number_max_students)
                        {
                        Program.AllStudents[Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student.id].id].coursesIP.Add(courseid);
                        Program.AllStudents[Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student.id].id].noCoursesIP++;

                        Program.AllCourses[courseid].number_current_students++;
                        Program.AllCourses[courseid].enrolled_students.Add(Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student.id].name);
                        Program.SaveSerial();
                        Program.SaveCourses();
                        MessageBox.Show("You Have Succesfully Registered to the course.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, This course had reached its maximum number of students.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                        }
                    }



            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Available course with this code. Re-enter code please.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
        }
```

i really dont know whats wrong

Comment: The student isn't in the AllStudents dictionary. It's there in the error message. Also `Program.AllStudents[Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student.id].id]` What? Why are you doing this?

Comment: if the student is not in allstudents dictionary i wouldnt be able to login at the mainmenu but i do. @john

Comment: Is the id for StudentPanel.student.id correct?

Comment: i use this to access the coursesip or finished

Comment: this code works on console version but nt in gui

Comment: `Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student‌​.id].....` is sufficient. You don't need to wrap it again.
As for your error, just add a breakpoint and check the values. I guarantee that the id is wrong or not contained within the dictionary.

Comment: all of the statements are else if, do i still need the breaks?

Comment: If you add a breakpoint you can debug into the code using step in / step over. When your code runs, it will stop at the breakpoint you've set and then youn can inspect the values of the variables at that point in the execution.
See here:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Visual-Studio-Shorts/Using-Breakpoints-for-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2015

Comment: added Program.AllStudents[StudentPanel.student‌​.id] but nothing fixed

Comment: That was a side comment. As I said before, the student id IS NOT present in the dictionary. I've provided you with information on how to debug your code using breakpoints to inspect the variables mid-execution. I'm not sure what you expect but I won't be responding further as I've got better things to do with my time.